# Viewing controller sent variables via Chrome dev javascript console

Tags: javascript, grails

Code like this on my GSP or template will show me controller sent variables in the Chrome dev tools javascript console:

```
<script>
    console.log("${recordToEdit.redIssues}"); // I see a list with elements in the console
</script>
```

I know it works because I see this:

```
[No address provided., No telephone number provided., No accounts found.]
```

but is there a way to see it interactively at the console? I tried the following commands but couldn't get it to work:

```
console.log("${recordToEdit.redIssues}")
${recordToEdit.redIssues} VM1892:2
undefined
console.log(${recordToEdit.redIssues})
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
console.log${recordToEdit.redIssues}
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to see it interactively with the way that you are trying to do things now. It works when it is embedded in the GSP or template with `<script></script>` tags because the `"${recordToEdit.redIssues}"` expression is a [GString](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Strings+and+GString) which is evaluated on the server side. When the GSP page is rendered, `recordToEdit.redIssues` is converted to a string containing it's value.

The JavaScript console has no knowledge of the server side code that you are running, only the static HTML content that it receives. That being said, you can still accomplish the functionality that you are looking for (to a degree).

You can access the same server side variable by setting the value to a global JavaScript variable on the GSP or template that you are using like this:

```
<script>
    window.redIssues = "${recordToEdit.redIssues}";
</script>
```

Then, in the Chrome DevTools console, you can access the value just by typing in `redIssues` and hitting enter. Note that the value won't be dynamic, it will only display what the original `recordToEdit.redIssues` value was when the page was rendered.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Appreciate it.